# Trying to find the user belonging to a has_many through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what I think is an instance of a record. It's a has many through record that belongs to user and account. I have this instance and I'm trying to find the user that belongs to it. This seems very simple because I have the user_id right on this instance. But when I call membership.user it returns an undefined method error? I really can't seem to figure this one out. Here is my code:

### Controller:

```
def owner
  owner = current_account.account_memberships.where(admin: true)
end
```

This will return this record:

```
  [#<AccountMembership:0x007fabf7cf9978
  id: 1,
  user_id: 1,
  account_id: 1,
  admin: true,
  worker: false,
  created_at: Sun, 22 Jan 2017 04:25:37 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 22 Jan 2017 04:25:37 UTC +00:00>]
```

If I call this `owner.id` I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for #<AccountMembership::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fabfcc0c1f0>
```

Did you mean?  ids

Here are the models:

### USER

```
has_many :account_memberships
has_many :accounts, through: :account_memberships
```

### Account

```
has_many :account_memberships
has_many :users, through: :account_memberships
```

### Account_memberships

```
belongs_to :account
belongs_to :user
```

I'm doing something wrong I just don't know what. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def owner
  owner = current_account.account_memberships.where(admin: true)
end
```

In the above method, owner is an ActiveRelation. You will need to call `first` to be able to get the actual order. You can also convert activerelation to an array by calling `to_a`

```
current_account.account_memberships.where(admin: true).first.id
```